# Why is netstat -n different between Solaris and Linux and how can I make it the same?

Tags: linux, networking, solaris, netstat

When I run `netstat -n` on Solaris I get different results from `netstat -n` on Linux, 
even though according to the manual pages in Solaris and Linux the `-n` flag should do the same thing.

My question:

Please advise me how to run `netstat` in Linux so that I will get the same results as I get in Solaris.

EXAMPLE:

**Solaris**

```
 netstat -n | head-10

TCP:IPv4
LocalAddress       RemoteAddress   SwindSend-QRwindRecv-Q   State
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10.119.99.77.9495   10.106.97.118.60823  5888     049640     0CLOSE_WAIT
 10.119.99.77.33121  10.119.99.77.1521   49152     049152     0ESTABLISHED
 10.119.99.77.1521   10.119.99.77.33121  49152     049152     0ESTABLISHED
 10.119.99.77.1521   10.119.99.112.54374 63702     049232     0ESTABLISHED
 127.0.0.1.45459     127.0.0.1.8886      49152     049152     0ESTABLISHED
 10.119.99.77.7777   10.115.244.53.63575  5888     049220     0CLOSE_WAIT
```

**Linux**

```
 netstat -n | head -10
 Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:14407             127.0.0.1:20281             ESTABLISHED 
 tcp        0      0 10.106.207.143:61623        10.106.207.143:1521         ESTABLISHED 
 tcp        0      0 10.106.207.143:61630        10.106.207.143:1521         ESTABLISHED 
 tcp        0      0 10.106.207.143:61624        10.106.207.143:1521         ESTABLISHED 
 tcp        0      0 10.106.207.143:61625        10.106.207.143:1521         ESTABLISHED 
 tcp        0      0 10.106.207.143:61627        10.106.207.143:1521         ESTABLISHED 
 tcp        0      0 10.106.207.143:1521         10.106.207.143:32263        ESTABLISHED 
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20281             127.0.0.1:14407             ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: When I run `netstat -n` on the two systems, the `-n` flag behaves in the same way, although the two programs format their outputs a little differently.  Can you explain a little about how you want the Linux output to look and why you want it that way?

Comment: please see my update question

Comment: Pasting isn't the same as explaining. We see your 2 examples, now what's the goal? You need the Rwind/Swind information? Just reorder the columns? Or for some unholy reason you need byte-for-byte mimicry?

Comment: @Eytan Why aren't you explaining what precisely you expect and why, as already asked by Wumpus ? You accepted an answer that suggests a undoable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux's netstat is from GNU's net tools, Solaris's isn't (Windows has its own too, so do the BSD's). You can install GNU on Solaris if you want GNU behavior.

Comment: net-tools is *not* a GNU project, but GPLv2 licenced

Answer (score 3):

Linux `netstat` comes from [net-tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/) which is not part of the GNU tools
 although licensed under the GPL.

Solaris `netstat` originally comes from SVR4 netstat.

Like most administrative commands, `netstat` is not standardized by POSIX so there is a large variation between the various implementations supported options and their output.

`net-tools` `netstat` is then Linux specific so there is **no way** to install it on Solaris.